# The best data type to store 0, 1, null values

Tags: php, mysql

I have three values: `0`, `1`, `NULL`. Now I want to know, what data type is fine for that column?

But the way, `NULL` is default of that column *(in the database)* and I achieve `0` and `1` form parameter (get method) of URL. Something like this:

```
www.example.com/?q=param=0
```

And then

```
$var = isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] : null;
```

And then

```
INSERT INTO table(col) values ($var);
```

Comment: I'd use tinyint, or boolean, which I think is just `tinyint(1)`

Comment: `int(1) unsigned NULL`

Comment: Or even `BIT(1) NULL`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## **It's 2019! This was marked correct years ago. Please see Paul Spiegel's answer directly below this one for a more modern answer.** #

TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL

tinyint's are perfect for booleans

Comment: 2022 and Paul's answer is still valid

Answer (score 14):

#### UPDATE

Since MySQL (8.0.16) and MariaDB (10.2.1) both implemented the CHECK constraint, I would now go with

```sql
bool_val TINYINT UNSIGNED CHECK(bool_val <= 1)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e086ebe5a882a04317c57fced5dbda66)

or

```sql
bool_val TINYINT CHECK(bool_val IN(0,1))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d911533dea202748f6e73f5707029eb6)

#### Original answer

I would use [Bit-Value Type - BIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html)

```sql
BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

`BIT(1)` needs 1 Byte of storage, wich is the same as `TINYINT(1)` does. The difference is that `BIT(1)` only accepts the values `0` and `1` (or `b'0'` and `b'1'`) while `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED` accepts values from `0` up to `255`. The length defined in the brackets for `TINYINT` does not take any affect to values that can be stored. It is only an information for clients, how to display the values (e.g. if you use `ZEROFILL`).

Comment: bit would likely be best if his needs were only 0,1. but he also mentioned null. technically 3 values in total.

Comment: @Conceptz - `BIT` can also store `NULL` like every datatype can by default. You have to explicitly define it `NOT NULL` if you don't want it to be `NULL`. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470d14/1)

Comment: actually, this is the correct answer, while TINYINT is less precise, even if the storage required is the same. Remember the value given as an argument of the datatype (ie `(1)`) only indicates the _display_ length, and does not change the behaviour.